# Did I choose the right tenses for these verbs?

Tags: tenses

> I received the parcel this morning, I was a bit surprised when I opened it that you **did not include** a flexi with the LP because I **told** you in my answer to your last email that I **preferred** a flexi to a discount code . After reading the message included in the parcel I understood that my answer had not been sent and was still in my draft folder.

LP means  33 rpm vinyl record andflexi 45 rpm very thin vinyl record

I am not sure about the tense of these verbs:

"Did not include" seems good to me as it happened after I opened the parcel.

"Told" and "preferred" also seem good to me because the time it is happening is today so the only past.  No need for past perfect here, I think, but I am not sure.

Comment: Question more suited to English Language Learners?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as Kate Bunting already said, it would belong at ELL, not here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use past perfect for "...**had told**..." because you are explaining what you thought after opening the parcel. The rest are acceptable. "...**preferred**..." should remain in past simple because you are then explaining what you said in your answer.

I hope this helps!

Comment: would it be better to use had not included because it happened before opening . Why "told" does not match , the sequence of events is clear because I wrote that my answer was done after your last email and it seems obvious that this email was written  before the parcel was sent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you did use the right tenses, but using the past perfect might emphasize your message a bit more. You could instead say: "I **told** you in my answer to your last email that **I had preferred** a flexi to a discount code" It emphasizes that the preference was already established before the communication in the past.